# Improving Canny Edge Detection

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

When I run the cv.Canny edge detector on drawings, it detects hundreds of little edges densely packed in the shaded areas. How can I get it to stop doing that, while still detecting lighter features like eyes and nose? I tried blurring too.

Here's an example, compared with an [online photo tool](https://online.rapidresizer.com/photograph-to-pattern.php).

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VcUa.jpg).
[Output of online tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYhjJ.png).
[My python program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFJ5E.png)

Here's my code:

```
def outline(image, sigma = 5):
    image = cv.GaussianBlur(image, (11, 11), sigma)
    ratio = 2
    lower = .37 * 255
    upper = lower * ratio
    outlined = cv.Canny(image, lower, upper)

    return outlined
```

How can I improve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

**Morphologic edge out is the absolute difference between a mask and the dilated mask**

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Threshold (as mask)
- Dilate the thresholded image
- Compute the absolute difference
- Invert its polarity as the edge image
- Save the result

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread("cartoon.jpg")

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# morphology edgeout = dilated_mask - mask
# morphology dilate
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
dilate = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

# get absolute difference between dilate and thresh
diff = cv2.absdiff(dilate, thresh)

# invert
edges = 255 - diff

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("cartoon_thresh.jpg", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("cartoon_dilate.jpg", dilate)
cv2.imwrite("cartoon_diff.jpg", diff)
cv2.imwrite("cartoon_edges.jpg", edges)

# display it
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("dilate", dilate)
cv2.imshow("diff", diff)
cv2.imshow("edges", edges)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Thresholded image:

[image]

Dilated threshold image:

[image]

Difference image:

[image]

Edge image:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I thought that canny edge detection was the best option. It worked very well on other examples. Why do you think your method worked better than canny on this one? Is there a certain kind of image you expect it to work better on, or do you think your method will be better overall compared to cv2.canny?

Comment: Also, the RapidResizer tool still seems to do better with removing shading and preserving original edges. Any idea how to get closer to that? Maybe you can understand their method: https://pastebin.com/atzeKipy

Comment: Add median filtering between the gray command and the thresh command `median = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 3)`. Or use any other good noise filtering process that won't affect the detection of edges otherwise, you may have to modify the dilation amount.

Comment: If you are willing to use Python Wand and not OpenCV, then Python Wand is based upon ImageMagick, which has other noise filtering processes. Another possible approach in OpenCV would use kmeans clustering rather than simple thresholding. But I have not tested that.

Comment: What does changing the dilation amount do? When I run your code, the text gets hollowed out, i.e. the edges of the letters are extracted. Why is that happening? It's not happening on that website.

Comment: Also, the Canny edge detector often gives "double edges" like this: https://i.imgur.com/PBljKfH.png. While your method gives a single edge: https://i.imgur.com/fJqcTc0.png. Why does this happen? Is there anything we can do with canny edge detector so it doesn't make double edges?

Comment: Here's a test sample I'd like it to work on: https://imgur.com/a/5zvv8tT

Comment: I do not believe you can change Canny behavior to deal with that.

Comment: What does your other tool produce for that extra image? That other site uses some other convolution based method. But I cannot follow their coding style.

Answer (score 1):

I was successfully able to make `cv.Canny` give satisfactory results by changing the kernel dimension from (11, 11) to (0, 0), allowing the kernel to be dynamically determined by sigma. By doing this and tuning sigma, I got pretty good results. Also, `cv.imshow` distorts images, so when I was using it to test, the results looked significantly worse than they actually were.